# Ajax - Bootstrap modal screen - keeps redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to achieve a modal screen that loads an Ajax page holding an artist profile.

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Support for AJAX loaded modal window.
    // Focuses on first input textbox after it loads the window.
    $('[data-toggle=modal]').click(function() {

    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
    $(url).modal('open');
    } else {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
    $('<div class="modal hide fade">' + data + '</div>').modal();
    }).stop();
    }
    });
});
```

Here is my HTML that is loaded by Ajax:

```
<div class="modal-header">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
<h3><?php echo $model->display_name; ?></h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p><?php echo $model->description ?></p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('.modal-body > form').submit();">Save Changes</a>
<a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
</div>
```

This is an example link:

```
<a class="artistOpenModal" data-toggle="modal" href="/index.php?r=artist/modal/id/25"><div style="height: 37.5px; top: 187.5px;" id="25" class="artist"><strong>Question Mark</strong> 15:45 - 45 min</div></a>
```

I am using jquery 1.10 and the latest version of bootstrap.

My page keeps redirecting to the url specified in the href of my a tag.

Do you see any obvious reasons in my code for this behaviour?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Try returning false at the end of your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change href attribute to something like `data-href` as href always leads to page load..

```
<a class="artistOpenModal" data-toggle="modal" data-href="/index.php?r=artist/modal/id/25"><div style="height: 37.5px; top: 187.5px;" id="25" class="artist"><strong>Question Mark</strong> 15:45 - 45 min</div></a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Support for AJAX loaded modal window.
    // Focuses on first input textbox after it loads the window.
    $('[data-toggle=modal]').click(function(event) {

    var url = $(this).attr('data-href');
    if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
    $(url).modal('show');
    } else {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
    $('<div class="modal hide fade">' + data + '</div>').modal('show');
    }).stop();
    }
    });
});
```

else use `event.preventDefault();` inside your click handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Support for AJAX loaded modal window.
        // Focuses on first input textbox after it loads the window.
        $('[data-toggle=modal]').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('data-href');
            if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
               $(url).modal('open');
            } else {
                $.get(url, function(data) {
                    $('<div class="modal hide fade">' + data + '</div>').modal('show');
                }).stop();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I tried your code and it's obvious my page is not refreshing anymore, but the modal is not opening. 

    14:49:47.895 SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead jquery.min.js:1
    14:49:47.901 Error: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one
    14:49:48.604 Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.


I noticed that there is no sign from the ajax load so I assume it is simply not fired but I cant figure out why.

Comment: you need to call .modal('show') to open the modal. Check my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Support for AJAX loaded modal window.
   // Focuses on first input textbox after it loads the window.
   $('[data-toggle=modal]').click(function() {
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
         $(url).modal('open');
      } else {
         $.get(url, function(data) {
            $('<div class="modal hide fade">' + data + '</div>').modal();
         }).stop();
      }
      return false;
   });
});
</script>
```

Hope it helps